# Python: Declaring a global object as an instance variable

Tags: python, list, variables, global, functor

I am writing an application in Python that relies heavily on global list variables. Each function in the program applies a change to one or all of these global lists.
While coding, I found that I required several functions involving movements of elements between the global lists, all of which involved the same lines of code--so I wrote an appropriate functor class.

The program below summarizes what I am doing. I will reference it to describe the problem occurring in my application:

```
#Global List variables
garbage=[]
paper=[]
metal=None

class movementFunctor:
    def __init__(self,source,destination):
        self.source=source
        self.destination=destination
    def __call__(self,item):
        self.source.remove(item)
        self.destination.append(item)

GtoP=movementFunctor(garbage,paper)
GtoM=movementFunctor(garbage,metal)
PtoM=movementFunctor(paper,metal)

def main():
    global garbage,paper,metal
    metal=[]
    #initialize garbage, paper, and plastic with numbers 0 to 5
    for i in range(5):
        garbage.append(i)
        paper.append(i)
        metal.append(i)
    GtoP(2)

    #Problem Code---------------------------------------------------------------------
    PtoM(2)
    #Problem Code---------------------------------------------------------------------
main()
```

My functor class, movementFunctor, specifies a source global variable list and a destination global variable list as parameters for instance variables. Then, the **call** operator specifies the movement of an item from the source list to the destination.

I thought this design would be successful; however, I have reached an error in the line 'PtoM(2)'

```
line 11, in __call__self.destination.append(item)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

One of the global lists, metal, was initialized to None, but main should have assigned it a new empty list []. So why would the PtoM functor run to the problem of metal being declared as None, when it was assigned the empty list?

I cannot find any information online or from previous posts regarding problems/intricacies of setting global variables as instance variables for a class.

I am new to the Stack Overflow forum, so please forgive/point out any conventions I have not followed well in posting this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created your `PtoM` before calling `main`.  At that time, `metal` was None, so `PtoM` set its destination to None.  It does not "watch" the variable `metal` to see if something else was assigned.

The solution is to either assign `metal = []` at the beginning, or move the creation of your `PtoM` and others inside `main`, after `metal` is set.

Comment: Beat me to it :). I would also add a link to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) regarding parameter passing in python.

Comment: That link really clarifies how variables work. I have learned a lot from it, and I see that my problem stems from this misunderstanding of pass by value and pass by reference in Python.